# radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n!(2x+1)^n}$

Tags: calculus

To find the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n!(2x+1)^n}$
I tried the ratio test, 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)!(2x+1)^{n+1}}{n!(2x+1)^n}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|(n+1)(2x+1)\right|,$$
and if this $<1$ then the series converges.
But this goes to infinity if $(2x+1)\neq 0$.

In this case is the radius of convergence is $0$?

Comment: Yes, it is zero.

Comment: Does the interval of convergence is zero then?

Comment: I think you have to find coeff. of $x^n$ first...

Comment: Also note that radius of convergence zero does not mean the domain of convergence is void. It *does* converge for one point... which one?

Answer (score 1):

Your computations are O.K.

Consequence: the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n!(2x+1)^n}$ converges $ \iff x=-1/2$.